# Get count and result from SQL query in Go

Tags: sql, go

I'm running a pretty straightforward query using the `database/sql` and `lib/pq` (postgres) packages and I want to toss the results of some of the fields into a slice, but I need to know how big to make the slice.

The only solution I can find is to do another query that is just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName;`.

Is there a way to both get the result of the query AND the count of returned rows in one query?

Comment: you cant just check the result count? rows.count() or something?

Comment: i didnt find a way to check count but did find this.. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/iHrXJj5MX_A  mentions setting the length of slice to 0 and it will grow once you append to it

Comment: As far as I can tell, that is the right answer. If you add an answer @JamieD77 I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, the problem is that the database cursor may not be enumerated to the end so the database does not really know how many records you will get before you actually read all of them. The only way to count (in general case) is to go through all the records in the resultset.

But practically, you can enforce it to do so by using subqueries like

```
select *, (select count(*) from table) from table
```

and just ignore the second column for records other than first. But it is very rude and I do not recommend doing so.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do sub queries. I ended up doing `SELECT (select count(*) FROM observations WHERE profile_id=$1 AND year=$2 AND month=$3) as count,  year, month, profile_id, FROM observations WHERE profile_id=$1 AND year=$2 AND month=$3`, id, date.Year(), int(date.Month()))`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for but you can call the @@Rowcount function to return the count of the previous select statement that has been executed.

```
SELECT mytable.mycol FROM mytable WHERE mytable.foo = 'bar'

SELECT @@Rowcount
```

If you want the row count included in your result set you can use the the OVER clause ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx))

```
SELECT mytable.mycol, count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY mytable.foo) AS 'Count' FROM mytable WHERE mytable.foo = 'bar'
```

You could also perhaps just separate two SQL statements with the a ; . This would return a result set of both statements executed.

Comment: Did you miss the part of the question where the OP says they are using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Actually yes I did since it was tagged as SQL . Ie I am running a query use the database/SQL  in the question. Should I remove my answer?

Answer (score -2):

You would used count(*)

```
SELECT count(distinct last)
FROM (XYZTable)
WHERE date(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) >= '2013-10-28' AND
id = 90 ;
```

Comment: that just returns the count.